# Hibernate: Query performance drop after some replication

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm developing a farm management system. One of the basic questions is to list the animals by type and that they are alive (`inFarm = true`). The method that performs this query follows below.

```
public List<T> findByInFarm(T model, boolean inFarm) throws DAOException {

    List<T> animalList = null;
    EntityManager em = JpaHelper.getEntityManager();
    Query query = em
            .createQuery("SELECT a FROM " + model.getClass().getSimpleName() + " a WHERE a.inFarm = :inFarm");
    query.setParameter("inFarm", inFarm);
    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        animalList = (List<T>) query.getResultList();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("findByInFarm() delayed " + (end - start) + " millis");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException(e.getCause().toString());
    } finally {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
    return animalList;
}
```

The query returns the expected result, but after running the same query a few times, performance drops a lot. I inserted a `System.currentTimeMillis ()` before `query.getResultList ()` and then one to measure query performance and ran the test below.

```
public void test() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            List<Cow> cowList = new Cow().findByInFarm(true);
            new Thread().sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the result obtained after some repetitions:

- findByInFarm() delayed 1017 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 615 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 606 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 591 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 566 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 561 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 586 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 588 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 546 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 3036 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 4876 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 4959 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 4904 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 4924 millis
- findByInFarm() delayed 4936 millis

The first queries are very fast but after the tenth repetition the time increases a lot. Could anyone give a tip where can be the possible causes of this?

Note: I am using Hibernate 5.2, Postgresql 9.4 and Java 8.

Comment: do you have configured connection pool ?

Comment: also read this https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/07/12/the-best-way-to-detect-database-connection-leaks/

Comment: `new Thread().sleep(2000);` is a bad pattern.  `sleep()` is a static method so you are creating a thread object just to do the sleep.  That should be `Thread.sleep(2000)`.

Comment: How big is this list?  Are you running out of memory?   Maybe try animalList.clear() after each time?  Maybe try increasing the memory of your test program with -Xmx2g (or more) to see if the delay happens at a different point?

Comment: @sbjavateam, you're right, a connection pool was missing. Follow the tutorial on this [site](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/) and solved my problem. Thank you.